# как запустить setInterval по отдельной команде?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть код, который нужно повторять несколько раз. Мне нужно, чтобы `setInterval` начался по команде, то есть изначально `setInterval` задан, но он не запущен, и только когда определенная команда дана из другой части программы - повторения начинаются.

Comment: вызывайте `setInterval` "когда определенная команда дана из другой части программы"

Comment: То-есть мне нужно сувать `setInterval` в `observer`? 

`MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      if(offerPanel.display != 'none'){`

Comment: я не знаю про "сувать", в вопросе про observer ничего нет. `setInterval` это функция, которая запускает таймер и возвращает идентификатор интервала. Вот из этого и исходите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//место где будет вызываться
function startInterval(){
    setInterval( say, 500)
}

// функция которая будет исполняться
function say() {
    console.log("таймер сработал")
}

// запуск для примера
startInterval()
```